# Android Splashscreen not displaying

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am trying to implement a splashscreen into my app.
Unfortunately, nothing appears with the code I am using now, it just jumps straight into my first activity.
Here is the code from my launch_screen.xml file, which is in my drawable folder:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splashscreen2"
            android:gravity="center"
        />

    </layer-list>
```

Note that the drawable file is a vector asset.

And here is the code from my styles.xml file, where I create a new theme using this launch_screen.xml file:

```
       <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
```

Code from my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ViewEventsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: @VrushiPatel edited my code to include this

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use a seperate Activity for the splash screen you can set the Splash theme on the Activity in the Manifest file:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

In the Activity before the `onCreate` super call reset the theme to your `AppTheme`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: This is the only valid answer so far. I see no point to intentionally slow up app start time only to show splash

Comment: @minikate are you sure the issue is not in the Splash screen drawable itself? Have you tried displaying a full screen color drawable first? To see if that works?

Comment: @Mickverm  I think you're right.. when I try to display the image I get the following error:

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marykate.marykatefordefyp/com.example.marykate.marykatefordefyp.ViewEventsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700a2



Not sure how to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

create normal activity and design in xml file then using handler post delayed option.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //startactivity
            finish();
        }
    }, 7000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not delaying the start of new activity from splash screen which not showing the splash screen.

Try :-

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(yourIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Where do I put this Handler?

Comment: In on Create of splash activity

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `intent-filter` to your SplashScreen in `Manifest`. For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> //This line
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this line included in my manifest already. I edited my question above to show this.

Comment: @minikate can you share `ViewEventsActivity` class ?

Comment: It's just my first activity, there is no reference to the splashscreen in this activity

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my code for the splash screen and it works very well:**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_activiyt);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Where SplashScreenActivity is standard activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: This is antipattern and it also shows you don't even understand what is splash screen purpose. Splash screen is not intended to slow down app startup

Comment: @user1209216 you are right if you need show splash screen until your data will be loaded. But sometimes there is requirement to show splash every time. In my app I need show every time.

Comment: This is not SplashScreen, it's loading screen. You have no any splash screen  and your app starts without splash screen, then it shows loading screen. Initial ugly wihte screen is still there with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mickverm answer is correct, there is one problem with it - splash screen will be shown every time activity is recreated by system. So, in my apps I always use dedicated activity for splash screen. However activity has no layout and only launcher theme set, so it loads immediately.

It's described here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/
Don't use any approach with handler/sleep and full activity unless you really need to (for example, to do something in background and show progress on splash screen)